# How to get Python interactive console in current namespace?

Tags: python, variables, namespaces, console, read-eval-print-loop

I would like to have my Python code start a Python interactive console (REPL) in the middle of running code using something like code.interact().  But the console that code.interact() starts doesn't see the variables in the current namespace.  How do I do something like:

mystring="hello"

code.interact()

... and then in the interactive console that starts, I should be able to type mystring and get "hello".  Is this possible?  Do I need to set the "local" argument of code.interact() to something?  What would this be set to? How should it be called?

Comment: refs: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-debug-python-with-an-interactive-console

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

```
code.interact(local=locals())
```

Comment: if you want the globals as well use the following:

    code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))

Comment: any chance to feed the changes (from the console, like a=3232) back into the caller script?

Answer (score 4):

For debug I usually use this

```
from pdb import set_trace; set_trace()
```

it may help

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to start the debugger, and then run `interact`:

```py
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Then from the debugger:

```
(Pdb) help interact
interact

        Start an interactive interpreter whose global namespace
        contains all the (global and local) names found in the current scope.
(Pdb) interact
*interactive*
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.10.0:

```
code.InteractiveConsole(locals=locals()).interact()
```

See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) for more details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

### How to mutate both globals() and locals() from code.interact

Unfortunately `code.interact` doesn't let you pass both `globals()` and `locals()` from the current namespace unless you copy them into a single dict like `code.interact(local={**globals(), **locals()})`, but then changes you make to `globals()` and `locals()` won't be persisted.

However you can work around this by subclassing the console and overriding its `runcode` method:

```py
import code
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    pass

class MyInteractiveConsole(code.InteractiveConsole):
    """Extends InteractiveConsole to also pass globals to exec."""
    def __init__(self, globals, *args, **kwargs):
        code.InteractiveConsole.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.globals = globals
    def runcode(self, code):
        try:
            exec(code, self.globals, self.locals)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except:
            self.showtraceback()
```

Having defined this somewhere, you can use it similarly to `code.interact`:

```py
MyInteractiveConsole(globals(), locals()).interact()
```

Except that this will let you read and mutate both globals and locals:

- `x = 7` will set a local
- `global x; x = 7` will set a global

and when you leave the interactive console with Ctrl+D (or Ctrl+Z then Enter on Windows), the changes you made should persist in your `globals()` and `locals()`.

*Caveat:* The [docs for locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) warn:

> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

so don't rely on these mutations to `locals()` for anything mission-critical. [PEP 558](https://peps.python.org/pep-0558/) and [PEP 667](https://peps.python.org/pep-0667/) go into more detail, and might make `locals()` behave more consistently in future versions of Python.