# code.interact and imports/definitions visibility

Tags: python, function, scope, visibility, python-import

I don't quite understand where **imports** and **function definitions** are **visibile** in a python module.
Here's a simplification of my case:

```
from scapy.all import *

def getA():
    return 0

def getB():
    return getA() + 1

def getC():
    code.interact(local=locals()) 
    return 3

def main():
    print getA()
    print getB()
    print getC()
    exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, everything goes smoothly until I reach function `getC` and a command prompt appears, **a lot** of what I should see **is missing**.

- getA() and getB() aren't visible
- scapy, which was in the imports, isn't visible either

Why does this happen? What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment above, the solution is:

```
code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
```

(taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165493/how-to-get-python-interactive-console-in-current-namespace#comment17527678_7165575))

Answer (score 8):

You are confusing [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals). In a function scope, `locals()` lists *only* names defined in the function itself.

Use `globals()` instead.

```
>>> bar = 'baz'
>>> def foo():
...     spam ='eggs'
...     print locals()
...
>>> foo()
{'spam': 'eggs'}
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'foo': <function foo at 0x108a027d0>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

Comment: Oh ok. My purpose was to open up a command prompt to inspect the value of variables and possibly continue manually. Until now I only had one big script, so I guess that's why `locals()` worked. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Well, if I do `code.interact(local=globals()) ` all the local definitions are lost. Is there any way I can do what I mentioned in my comment above?

Comment: OK, found it: `code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals())) `   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165493/how-to-get-python-interactive-console-in-current-namespace#comment17527678_7165575